# How to transfer ownership of a value to C code from Rust?

Tags: rust, ffi, ownership

I'm trying to write some Rust code with FFI that involves C taking ownership of a struct:

```
fn some_function() {
    let c = SomeStruct::new();
    unsafe {
        c_function(&mut c);
    }
}
```

I want `c_function` to take ownership of `c`.  In C++, this could be achieved by the `release` method of `unqiue_ptr`. Is there something similar in Rust?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `std::unique_ptr` type in C++ corresponds to `Box` in Rust, and `.release()` [corresponds to `Box::into_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw).

```
let c = Box::new(SomeStruct::new());
unsafe {
    c_function(Box::into_raw(c));
}
```

Note that the C function should return the ownership of the pointer to Rust to destroy the structure. It is incorrect to free the memory using C's `free` or C++'s `delete`.

```
pub unsafe extern "C" fn delete_some_struct(ptr: *mut SomeStruct) {
    // Convert the pointer back into a Box and drop the Box.
    Box::from_raw(ptr);
}
```

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` has a template parameter, `Deleter`, which defaults to `std::default_delete<T>`. It might be convenient to take advanage of this by providing an exposed Rust function to do the deletion instead. Alternatively, you might be able to specialize `std::default_delete` so that _all_ instances `unique_ptr<RustType>` get deallocated correctly.