# Returning a pointer to an object from a Rust library for later reuse?

Tags: rust, shared-libraries

I want to call a Rust library which will create an object `increment_engine` for me and return a pointer to it (or anything persistent). This engine would be given a parameter on creation.

Later I could call this object's `increment(a)` method and it would add the remembered parameter to `a` and return the result. Here is the code:

```java
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;

public class App {
  public interface MyLibrary extends Library {
      MyLibrary INSTANCE = (MyLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("myjavarust", MyLibrary.class);
      double addition(double a , double b);
      int set_increment_engine(double parameter);
      double use_increment_engine(int engine_id, double a);
  }

  public static void main() {
    int sum = MyLibrary.INSTANCE.addition(13.0,5.0);
    System.out.println(sum);  // this works and prints 18 (=13+5)

    engine_id = MyLibrary.INSTANCE.get_increment_engine(13.0);
    double  result = MyLibrary.INSTANCE.use_increment_engine(engine_id,5.0);
    System.out.println(result);  // this should also return 18 

  }
}
```

The last three lines of `main()` show how I would like to use the "increment engine"

The Rust pseudo-code should look like this.

```rust
extern crate libc;

use libc::{c_double, uint32_t};

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn addition(a: f64, b: f64) -> f64 {
    a + b
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn set_increment_engine(param: c_double) -> uint32_t {
    let engine = IncrementEngine { param: param };
    return_engine_id_somehow
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn use_increment_engine(engine_id: uint32_t, a: c_double) -> c_double {
    let engine = find_engine_somehow(engine_id);
    engine.increment(a)
}

struct IncrementEngine {
    param: c_double,
}

impl IncrementEngine {
    pub fn increment(&self, a: f64) -> f64 {
        a + self.param
    }
}
```

I have successfully tested the function "addition" which does not require the persistent "increment machine", but I would like to use the *engine* pattern (obviously for more complex things than incrementing a `double`). I have investigated many sites about passing data across library boundaries and there is lots of information on passing structures etc, but not so many on "persistent pointers". The only thing close to the solution is [in the Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/nomicon/ffi.html#targeting-callbacks-to-rust-objects) where the Rust library calls the caller back which allows for the object to persist, but it is really not applicable to my use-case.

`engine_id` in the example is an `int`, but presumably it would be some kind of pointer to the object created by `set_increment_engine`.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of [How to transfer ownership of a value to C code from Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42523354/155423)

Comment: I am NOT trying to transfer ownership to C (because than I would have to trasfer it back and forth all the time), but the "Rust FFI Omnibus" seems promissing from at first sight, I will have a look at it closely.

Comment: More specifically about the ownership - the example calls C function from Rust, but I do it the other way round - I call the rust function from C.

Comment: *I would have to trasfer it back and forth* — why do you believe that? Are you under the impression that transferring a pointer is an expensive operation?

Comment: Maybe it is usable as well, but it raises more questions: how do I return the ownership as result to the calling C function? How do I reuse it in the C code? How do I "retype" it in rust back to the object it refers to when called later from the C code? However I will look at both of these links and come back. Thanks a lot for both links.

Answer (score 3):

[This approach](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/objects/) can be taken:

```java
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;

public class App {
  public interface MyLibrary extends Library {
    MyLibrary INSTANCE = (MyLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("myjavarust", MyLibrary.class);
    long set_increment_engine(double parameter);
    double use_increment_engine(long engine, double a);
    void free_increment_engine(long engine);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long engine = MyLibrary.INSTANCE.set_increment_engine(13.0);
    double result = MyLibrary.INSTANCE.use_increment_engine(engine, 5.0);
    System.out.println(result);  // returns correctly 18.0
    MyLibrary.INSTANCE.free_increment_engine(engine);
  }
}
```

with this **lib.rs** code:

```rust
extern crate libc;

use libc::c_double;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn set_increment_engine(param: c_double) -> *mut IncrementEngine {
    let engine = IncrementEngine { param: param };
    Box::into_raw(Box::new(engine))
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn use_increment_engine(engine_ptr: *mut IncrementEngine, a: c_double) -> c_double {
    let engine = unsafe {
        assert!(!engine_ptr.is_null());
        &mut *engine_ptr
    };
    engine.increment(a)
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn free_increment_engine(engine_ptr: *mut IncrementEngine) {
    if engine_ptr.is_null() {
        return;
    }
    unsafe {
        Box::from_raw(engine_ptr);
    }
}

pub struct IncrementEngine {
    param: c_double,
}

impl IncrementEngine {
    pub fn increment(&self, a: f64) -> f64 {
        a + self.param
    }
}
```

Note that the function `addition` was removed as it only served for purpose of the question.

Comment: @Shepmaster I would be gratefull, if you look at the answer I have compiled. I have tested it and it seems to run fine, but maybe you could have some valuable insight. Thanks for the inspirational links, the credit for this answer should go to you, however I do not know how to do that...

Comment: The only thing I am not really sure about is the usage of long got the pointer on the java side.