# How to prevent double free and leaks with FFI

Tags: rust, ffi

I have a program, lets say it's in C and is closed source which I don't have access to. It  can load a dynamic rust library to do additional processing. One of the problems I'm facing is how to prevent double frees and memory leaks when the dynamic library does some processing. The program passes structs around as pointers and I need to call a function to free/drop the struct when unneeded. If the struct if passed back into the main C logic, that part of the program will track the pointer and destoy in when neccessary. If a struct is never passed back, then rust will be responsible for cleaning it up.

I have constructed the below code which appears to work but feels unelegant.

Couple of questions:

1. Am i right to use `cast`
2. Nothing is stopping someone from calling `get_interior` multiple times, is there a way to prevent that?
3. Feels like this should be a fairly common pattern in FFI, is there a better way to do this or standard pattern?

```rust
use std::mem::ManuallyDrop;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct FFI_Object {
    r: i32,
    value: f64,
}

pub struct Wrapper {
    consumed: bool,
    interior: ManuallyDrop<*mut FFI_Object>,
}

impl Wrapper {
    pub fn new(x: *mut FFI_Object) -> Self {
        Self {
            consumed: false,
            interior: ManuallyDrop::new(x),
        }
    }

    pub fn get_interior(&mut self) -> *mut FFI_Object {
        self.consumed = true;
        self.interior.cast() // again not sure if cast is correct
    }
}

impl Drop for Wrapper {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            if !self.consumed {
                free(self.interior.cast()); // is cast() right here?
            }
        }
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn do_leak() -> *mut FFI_Object {
    let m = new_object(); // Memory leak as C program won't free
    let n = new_object();

    n // C takes control and will free when needed
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn do_double_free() -> *mut FFI_Object {
    let m = new_object();
    free(m);

    m // C takes control and will cause a double free
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn do_no_leak() -> *mut FFI_Object {
    let m = Wrapper::new(new_object()); // Drop called immediately and freed
    let mut n = Wrapper::new(new_object()); // mut feels wrong

    n.get_interior() // Rust wont drop because "consumed", C will handle dropping
}

extern "C" {
    pub fn new_object() -> *mut FFI_Object;

    pub fn free(x: *mut FFI_Object);

}
```

Comment: Keeping track of whether an object has been "consumed" is unnecessary and error-prone. A better approach is to use Rust's move semantics instead. If a method is supposed to consume a struct, it should receive `self` by value. If you want to prevent the destructor of the consumed struct from being run, you can use `std::mem::forget(self)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume rather than wrapping the FFI_Object in a wrapper to consume it you could make a function that takes ownership of the object, forgets it and returns a raw pointer to the object. Rust should then not clean it up.

```
impl FFI_Object {
    fn let_go(mut self) -> *mut FFI_Object {
        let ptr: *mut FFI_Object = &mut self;
        std::mem::forget(self);
        ptr
    }
}
```

Edit:
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42523354/how-to-transfer-ownership-of-a-value-to-c-code-from-rust) post it is incorrect to hand ownership over the FFI boundary: So if C allocates then C should free, and if Rust allocates then Rust should free.